# Get JSON data from URL for PHP 5.1

Tags: php, json

I want to get data from an URL which gives output as JSON data.
From the below code I get the expected result in my localhost whose PHP version is 7 but not getting the result in my elastix 2.5 whose PHP version is 5.1.

What change in code is needed to be done to get the result in PHP 5.1?
What I think is that `file_get_contents` is not working in PHP 5.1.
Can anyone help me get rid of this problem?

```
$remote_url = "my_url";

// Create a stream
$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header' => "authorization:Basic MzY3Ojk4Nw=="                 
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

// Open the file using the HTTP headers set above

$file = file_get_contents($remote_url, false, $context);

$my_array = json_decode($file, true);
```

Comment: enable error reporting, you will get the error details

Comment: What is the problem/error? Without knowing the actual problem, you cannot get any helpful suggestion (for example, you can use curl or Guzzle but this is not probably the answer you expect)

Comment: if (!isset($my_array[0]['Policyno'])) {
    die('Not Found');}                                                                                                                 I have given this code at the end... but  it always returns 'Not Found'

Comment: the url contains json data like :    [{"Policyno":"213400962-0","ProposersName":"MOHTARAM  MD. ABDUL MANNAN  HOWLADER","ProposersAddress":"S/O- MD. ABDUS SALAM HOWLADER\r\nHOWLADER TRADERS \r\nDHAKA  FISH MARKET\r\n320/5 SOUTH JATRABARI\r\nDHAKA-1204","Riskdate":"31 Dec 2009","sumassured":600000.0,"planno":"16","Term":"12","mode":"Yly","TotalPremium":62820.0,"NextDueDate":"31 Dec 2016","NoOfInstalment":7.0,"MobileNo":null,"MaturityDate":"31 Dec 2021"}]